# How to delete all following rows once an observation/condition of interest has reached in the previous row R (right censoring)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Hope you can help with what I believe is a dplyr/tidyr problem:

**QUESTION**
How do I conditionally delete following observations once the first observation of interest was made? (right-censoring)

**DATA**

```
structure(list(record_id = c(120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
120321), day_count = c(579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 
587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599
), day_count_stop = c(580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 
588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600
), te_yn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), groups = structure(list(
    record_id = 120321, .rows = structure(list(1:21), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**EXPLANATION**

So I actually followed record_id 120321 from day 0 to day 732. In this example you see the days of follow-up from day 579 to 600.

I want to delete all rows after the day te_yn has become 1. That is the observation of interest. So at day 584, te_yn became 1.  I want to delete day 585 until the end.

Best Wishes

*This is part of a larger problem on survival analysis. If one is experienced with Cox PH analysis and would like to help, please view the link below:
[Coding help for Cox PH analysis with a categorical time-dependent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537918/coding-help-for-cox-ph-analysis-with-a-categorical-time-dependent-variable)*

Comment: `slice(data, 1:which(.$te_yn==1))`? It looks like you have several "observations of interest" however, and that will only choose the first one.

Comment: Hi Dubukay. 
Slicing from the first observation of interest is exactly what I want! 
However, when I slice with the following code 
`dataframe <- dataframe %>% slice(data, 1:which(. $te_yn==1))` , I receive the following error: " Error: `slice()` expressions should return indices (positive or negative integers)." What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I assume you'd have to do so for different record_id. Here I am grouping by that. See if this works for you.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(record_id) %>% filter(if(1 %in% te_yn) row_number() == 1: (which(te_yn == 1) -1) else TRUE)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   record_id [2]
   record_id day_count day_count_stop te_yn
       <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1    120321       579            580     0
 2    120321       580            581     0
 3    120321       581            582     0
 4    120321       582            583     0
 5    120321       583            584     0
 6    120322       579            580     0
 7    120322       580            581     0
 8    120322       581            582     0
 9    120322       582            583     0
10    120322       583            584     0
11    120322       584            586     0
12    120322       585            587     0
13    120322       586            588     0
14    120322       587            589     0
15    120322       588            590     0
>
```

Data used:

```
structure(list(record_id = c(120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 120321, 
120321, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 120322, 
120322, 120322, 120322), day_count = c(579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 
584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 
597, 598, 599, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588
), day_count_stop = c(580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 
588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 
580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590), te_yn = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Have added additional group to the original data.

Comment: Thank you, I have deleted the last -1, to include the day with the outcome of interest.

Comment: Oh , I understand:
So you tell R to filter from the first row until the row in which te_yn == 1. 

Thank you

Comment: I have got an error in the larger database. Here is the error and traceback:

`Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x argument of length 0 ℹ Input `..1` is `row_number() == 1:(which(te_yn == 1))`. ℹ The error occurred in group 1: record_id = 110001. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I think the issues lies in the fact that 110001 does not have the event of interest. So te_yn remains 0 across the entire follow-up. How should this be corrected?

Comment: @KBChu, so I've added additional group without te_yn having value 1, have posted the data and output in my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again, however, the output is not what I wanted. 
Using your data, what I want is a df with:
- for record_id 120321, the count continues until day 584 (thus include), because I want to see when te_yn has become 1 for the first time. 
- for record_id 120322, all day counts should be included, as no te_yn = 1 has occured.

Comment: @KBChu, have made the change, now the output has all rows for record_id 120322 and for 120321 has till 584. Please check now.

Comment: Fantastic. It works. It does give this warning which I will ignore haha: Warning messages:
1: In 1:(which(te_yn == 1)) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In row_number() == 1:(which(te_yn == 1)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: @KBChu, strange, I didn't get any warning, But if works for you, can you please accept my answer.